# "Archive" a table on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, archive

long time reader first time poster.

I recently started using ruby on rails so I am still very new to the environment (even though I have completed a few guides) so be gentle please.

What I want to do is create a sort of archive table of another table that the user can access at any time(via a different link on the website).

So for example, if I have the "users" table, I want to be able to archive old users but still give the option for someone to go and view them.
Basically, it will sort of have to delete the user from the initial table, and save his/her info in to the archived_users table.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I figured my comment was more of an answer, so posting it here and adding more info*

In this situation you're better off adding some sort if "active" flag to the users table, which you can flip on or off as needed. That way you don't need to worry about dealing with yet another model class, and you can reuse all the same view and controller structures. In your views, you can then simply "hide" any inactive users (and maybe only show inactive folks if the logged in user is an admin...etc).

You also have the freedom to include other meta data such as "deactivated on" (time stamp) for example.

Long story short, if you're concerned about performance, with proper indexing (and partitioning if necessary), you shouldn't really need to create a separate archive table.

The only reason I can think of to do this is if you're dealing with billions upon billions of records, and/or growing by an insane amount (which is probably not your case).

Comment: Thank you very much. A very simple solution that does exactly what I need to! One final question though, where is it better to set the default value of each new user to "active"?

Comment: @user3435450 I would set that in the database. So when you create your migration, you would simply add `:default => false` in the column definition. You could also make use of a `default_scope` to always set the value on load (don't like this idea, too much work), or add a `before_save` callback to autoset the value (also too much work). Either alternative is good only if for some reason you can't set default values in your database.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll have to bother you one last time though:)
So after doing all that, I need to create a link for the new ".../users/archive", where the user will be able to view the archived users.
From what I understand so far, that would mean that I need to go to the UsersController and add the "def archive end" lines somewhere in there and then run the "bundle exec rake routes" from the terminal.
But, after trying to go to the ".../users/archive" url, I get this error "Couldn't find User with id=archive" and
Extracted source:"def set_user
@user=User.find(params[:id])end"

Comment: @user3435450 `bundle exec rake routes` doesn't do anything other than showing you what routes you currently have. You need to add another route in your `routes.rb` for this path. The cleanest way is outlined [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes). I think you can get the idea from that link; I assume you have a `resources :users` in your routing file, so you'd basically add a `get 'archive', on: :collection` like they do in their example. You can do a `rake routes` to confirm `/users/archive` exists.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is probably to add a *column* called `deleted` on the original Users table. You can then filter out the old users in normal circumstances (preferably using a [default scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class)) but allow them to be seen/queried when needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Papertrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) might work for you.

It creates a "versions" table and logs create/update/destroy events for any class which includes `has_paper_trail`.  For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end

deleted_users = Papertrail::Version.where(item_type: User, event: "destroy")

deleted_users.last.reify.name # assuming the users table has a 'name' column
```